# Fast Stone Image Viewer - Creating one image out of multiple images

Tags: images, image-editing, image-processing, faststone-capture

I was wondering if there's a functionality within Fast Stone Image Viewer that allows you to "glue" several images together into a single image as sort of an image grid while keeping the original resolution.

Thank you!

Comment: In FastStone Capture editor: Tools | Combine Images into a Single Image File

Answer (score 2):

Under the ***Create*** menu there is the **Image Strip Builder** tool which sort of lets you do that (but only a single direction - horizontal or vertical - photo strip, and not a photo collage):
[image]

Comment: Sweet? I recently saw there's a "contact sheet" option to but haven't tried it yet. Any experience with that?

Comment: Not a lot (but it doesn't do what we discuss here)